# Moving process designed for web interface to a mobile interface

Tags: gui-design, mobile-application, mobile-web

I am currently moving a process designed for a web UI to a mobile UI and was wondering how the remaining steps (ie from step 2) could be translated to a mobile UI whilst reducing the number of user clicks:

**Step 1**

User clicks on Yes.

[image]

**Step 2**

User selects a case.

[image]

**Step 3**

User agrees to conditions and clicks on Next step.

[image]

**Step 4**

User selects an option which ends process.

[image]

How can I effectively translate steps 2-4 to mobile?

Comment: What have you tried? How do you think this would translate to mobile? This feels more like a design question than a UX questions as currently phrased. Also: you have a list view, an "accept terms", and a an action. This could all be made into a simple form using native components.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I can sort of see how it can be translated to mobile, but was wondering if any steps could be merged or skipped in order to reduce the number of clicks for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well one simple consideration is, in mobile you don't have "buttons" any more.  You just have the panels in question, and you touch on that panel to select that "thing".

Web ..

> Airfare 1 description blah blah    < buy! >
>
> Airfare 2 description blah blah    < buy! >
>
> ...
>
> Airfare 7 description blah blah    < buy! >

Wheres on the glass...

> Airfare 1 description blah blah
>
> Airfare 2 description blah blah
>
> ...
>
> Airfare 7 description blah blah

Each of the seven "blocks" will be on it's own little panel (UICollectionView, UITableView, or whatever your poison is).

The user just touches the relevant row, panel, to act on that one.

This would apply in **"Step 2"** in your example, for instance.

{Of course, furthermore, there are a couple somewhat common metaphors available which we all use everyday in messaging apps and the like.  So, sliding a panel left with your finger generally means something along the lines of "delete" or "see more options on that one" ... but set that complication aside. In any event, you don't have any buttons on glass, it's just understood you touch the "whole row" (panel, block, whatever) in which you're interested.}